# Blank menu, NullPointerException in Android Studio 0.2.5 when trying to create new module

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 4 modules in my project.  I could create new modules using Android Studio version 0.2.0.

Two days ago, I upgraded Android Studio to 0.2.5, and now when I go to create a new module, the window doesn't show any options.

[image: New module windows hint "Noting to show"]

I can't execute "New Module" either via File -> "New Module" or via right-clicking my project name in the Project tool window.

If I press finish, Android Studio throws a `NullPointerException`.  Here is the console output:

```
null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.TemplateWizardModuleBuilder.createModule(TemplateWizardModuleBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.NewModuleWizardrun(NewModuleWizard.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1021)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.NewModuleWizard.createModule(NewModuleWizard.java:79)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewModuleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewModuleAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitterrun(ActionMenuItem.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:892)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:230)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:104)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueuerun(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueuerun(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomaindoIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomaindoIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueuerun(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueuerun(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomaindoIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:679)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:503)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:332)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "4 module in my project,and i could new module when" means?  As it is, it is difficult to determine.

Comment: Having the same problem. @MarkSchultheiss: If you have a project with a few modules in it, and then go to create a new module, the window doesn't show any option.

Comment: I've got a hello world project from scratch and I get "Nothing to show" as well...

Comment: You "could new module" and now you "can't new module". You're missing a verb, can't what?

Comment: i create 4 module when my android studio version is 0.2.0.  and 2days ago i had updated android studio version to 0.2.5,then i can't new module any more . @Mark Schultheiss

Comment: As of version 0.3.5 trying to add a new module just hangs the program.

Comment: And as of 0.3.6 it seems to be working. The joys of preview releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add a new module by manually creating a new folder and copy/pasting:

- Another module IML file (renaming it after)
- build.gradle file from another module
- creating all the Android files manually (Manifest, RES files, SRC files)

Then if you restart Android Studio, it should see it a new module.

This is not the best solution but a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: thanks @lvanSF ,i did as you said,and i see a new module. as you said it is not the best solution.